# How to Make Multi Databases in Python Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, database, python-django-storages

What I mean is how to insert a model into another model in Python Django 
So I am working on a simple project of an online school.
we have classes, and in the classes we have subjects and in the subjects we got lessons so how to make a model in python django to add subjects to an individual class only. and add lessons to individual subject in a specific class, this is it, hope understand me well, thanks.

Comment: Read about database relations, that's what they are for. In Django docs, look up ForeignKey and Many-to-Many relationships. But start by reading the theory of relational databases (e.g. a MySQL tutorial).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreign key fields. Let's say you have Order model which has total price of order, Vendor and Merchant fields. In this case total price is a FloatField, but vendor and merchant is foreign key field and they take primary key of the related models.

```
from django.db import models

class Order(models.Model):

total_price = models.FloatField(default=None)

vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
merchant = models.ForeignKey(Merchant, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thank you so much, I think that what I was searching for, so I will go learn ForeignKeys, thanks :)

Comment: That's great, have fun :)